# I need to access to object data ( id - title - body )

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I need to access data.data[0].title

while printing

> data.data[0]

I get all object data
but while printing

> data.data[0].title

i can't access any data

// this is my ajax script

```
   <script>
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',

            success: function(data) {
                $('#test').html( JSON.stringify( data.data[0].title ) );

            }
        })
    </script>


  <p id="test" ></p>
```

Comment: try to print the data using console.log(data)

Comment: You probably dont need `JSON.stringify()`. Just use: `$('#test').html(data.data[0].title)`, provided your top-level data contains data key as an array

Comment: @illusion it doesn't work with me

Comment: what does your `data` object consist of? top-level one

Comment: what's the output of what salim suggested?

Comment: @illusion  {data: Array(2), status: true, error: null}

Comment: I think, there's an error server-side. You're not serializing the array as json encoded. I believe you're using laravel. are you returning eloquent objects from the ajax request?

Comment: I tested my API URL its working well and print all object data on console

Comment: when you tried `console.log(data)`, it displayed `{data: Array(2), status: true, error: null}`. what is the content of the inner `data`? try `console.log(data.data)` and share the output...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't need `JSON.stringify()`. @illusion is right! I guess your response Object structure is similar to:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "title": "This is the title"
    }]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://extendsclass.com/api/json-storage/bin/ebbfccb',  //replace this with your api URI
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',

            success: function(data) {
           $('#test').html(data.data[0].title);

            }
        })
    </script>


  <p id="test" ></p>
```

Comment: it doesn't print any data on html .... and i tried to console.log(data.data[0].title) its  undefined output

Comment: can you please update your question with the structure of the reponse that you are receiving? Just get a console log of data:  console.log(data)